# Sumar el resultado de una consulta teniendo en cuenta el UNION

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT   
CAST(F0.Cargo AS nvarchar(5))  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as Cargo , 
F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual,
CAST(F0.Nombre AS char(100))  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as Nombre ,
--convert (char(100) , F0.Nombre),
CAST(F0.codbodega AS char(100))  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as Codbodega , 
SUM(F0.Neto) AS Total , 

F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual/2-SUM(F0.Neto) AS Cupo_Disponible, 
F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual/2 as Cupo_Quincena
FROM (
SELECT T4.nombre AS Cargo, T4.CupoEndeudamientoMensual , T0.fecha,
REPLACE (RTRIM(T3.nombre),'','')+' '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.NOMBRE1),'','')+' '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.APELLIDO),'','')+' '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.APELLIDO1),'','') as Nombre,
T1.codbodega,T1.valor,T2.porcentaje,
CASE WHEN T0.codtipodcto='NC' THEN
ROUND((((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100))+(((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100)) * T2.porcentaje)/100))*t1.cantidad)*-1,2)
ELSE
ROUND((((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100))+(((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100)) * T2.porcentaje)/100))*t1.cantidad),2)
END AS 'Neto'
FROM  PRAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencfacturas T0  
                        INNER JOIN PRAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtofacturas  T1 ON T1.consecutivo=T0.consecutivo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
                        INNER JOIN PRAPORCIPOS.dbo.tbltarifas_iva     T2 ON T1.codiva=T2.codiva         COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
                        INNER JOIN PRAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios  T3 ON T3.codigo=T0.CODIGO         COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
                        INNER JOIN PRAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblgrupos_terceros T4 ON T4.codgrupo = T3.codgrupo
WHERE T3.ESEMPLEADO='TRUE'  AND T0.CODTIPODCTO IN ('FA','NC')  AND YEAR(T0.fecha)='2020' AND MONTH(T0.fecha)='01' AND DAY(T0.fecha) BETWEEN 02 AND 16 AND T0.codigo ='E-1037647327'  --CONVERT(DATE,T0.fecha) BETWEEN @FecIni AND @FecFin  AND T0.codigo like '%'+ @Buscar +'%'
) AS F0

GROUP BY F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual,F0.Cargo,  F0.Nombre, F0.codbodega

UNION 

El mismo query de arriba, pero con diferente base de datos
```

Como resultado obtengo la siguiente respuesta

[image: Resultado]

hasta ahora todo bien, lo que deseo es totalizar la columna **Total**, 
he intentado anidar la consulta, pero no he tenido una respuesta ya que usando el union supongo que es mas complejo.

¿Cómo más podria realizarlo?

Comment: a que te referis con anidar? y vos solo queres una fila mas con el total? o nuevas filas?

Comment: Si, una fila mas con el total de ambos registros, no lo publique completo porque son en 27 bases de datos, pero en si es la misma consulta usando el **Union**

Comment: con anidar me refiero a algo similar
select sum(A)+sum(B )   from (
select * from consuulta A 
union
select * from consulta B
)

Comment: No lo vas a poder hacer. que sentido tiene? si queres sumar, que sume quien recibe estos datos. Si no, tendrias que volver a calcular todo solo para hacer esa suma. Los problemas de la salida, los tiene que solucionar el que muestra los datos.

Comment: Mmmm niemp em eso tienes razon, el sentido es para simplificar al que va a operar el sistema el cual contiene un modulo donde dice el estado de cuenta de un empleado, pense hacerlo por aplicacion y ando intentandolo por aparte ya que por el motor de base de datos parece un dato redundante.

Comment: el modulo puede hacer la cuenta cuando recibe los datos... solo tiene que sumar esas filas...

Comment: Si, voy a realizarlo asi, pero muchas gracias de tomarse su tiempo analizar y responder

Comment: Entiendo que tienes una consulta grande y compleja, a la cual le quieres agregar una fila de total. Como ya te comentó Gonzalo, lo ideal es que lo resuelva la vista de los datos, sin embargo si quisieras que lo haga el sevidor, lo más sencillo es que crees una tabla temporal e insertes ahí todas las filas de esta consulta, luego simplemente listas las filas con un union, para el detalle y la sumatoria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen espero esto te ayude. Al generar el union lo que estas haciendo es generar una "tabla virtual" con el resultado de las dos consultas. Por lo tanto deberias hacer un select a la "tabla virtual" del resultado para realizar tu requerimiento te lo explico con el siguiente ejemplo.

[image: Tablas]

como puedes ver en este ejemplo tenemos a Tabla1, Tabla2 y a Resultado el cual es el union de las tablas mensionadas. Para ponerlo en sql seria lo siguiente:

```
Select campo1, campo2 from Tabla1
union
Select campo1, campo2 from Tabla2
```

esto generará la "tabla virtual" Resultado. Por lo tanto si quieres sumar uno de sus campos puedes generar un select extra a tabla resultado de la siguiente forma:

```
select sum(t.campo1) from
(
Select campo1, campo2 from Tabla1
union
Select campo1, campo2 from Tabla2
) as t
```

Comment: Gracias ante todo. voy a realizar la respectiva validacion acerca del ejemplo que me das y te estare comentando en caso de que funcione o no

Comment: Gracias, era lo que necesitaba, lo intende de muchas formas, pero a la final tu explicacion fue bastante legible, facil de hacerlo. pero al ser tantos union, estaba un poco perdido... pero ahora lo logre.. gracias!!